# Why does SQS FIFO queue with lambda trigger cannot guarantee only once delivery?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

I came across an [AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-sqs-fifo-as-an-event-source/) where it is mentioned only once delivery of a message is not guaranteed when the FIFO queue is used with a lambda trigger.

> Amazon SQS FIFO queues ensure that the order of processing follows the message order within a message group. However, it does not guarantee only once delivery when used as a Lambda trigger. If only once delivery is important in your serverless application, it’s recommended to make your function idempotent. You could achieve this by tracking a unique attribute of the message using a scalable, low-latency control database like Amazon DynamoDB.

I am more interested in knowing the reason behind this behaviour when it comes to lambda trigger. I assume, with standard queues only once delivery is not guaranteed since SQS stores messages in multiple servers for redundancy and high availability and there is a chance of same message getting delivered again while multiple lambdas polling the queue.

Can someone please explain the reason for the same behaviour in FIFO queue with lambda trigger or the working internally?

Answer (score 2):

By default lambda polls synchronously from SQS. So when lambda processes messages from the queue they become invisible i.e Visibility timeout gets triggered till the lambda either finishes the process to eventually delete them from the queue or fails to retry them again.

That's why lambda cannot guarantee exactly-once delivery since there can be a retry in lambda cause of timeout (15min max) or other code dependency errors.

To prevent this you either make your process idempotent or use [Batch response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#services-sqs-batchfailurereporting) to delete the message even in case of failure.